# Unknown error: Session deleted because of page crash from tab crashed

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium and Java to write a test.

Everything was fine till yesterday, when my test started to crash throwing out this error:

> unknown error: session deleted because of page crash from tab crashed

I thought this was related to my computer CPU but even after closing all other applications it happened again!! and if it's related to my CPU why it was working till yesterday? What should I do now?

Comment: The error is saying it has nothing to do with your CPU. Try to debug the code.

Comment: @ManishChristian But this code was working through last 3 months !!! and what does this error exactly mean? I googled it but no clue :(

Comment: That means some changes have been made, either to your code or at app side. Have you tried to debug the code?

Comment: @ManishChristian yes I did, nothing is changed in neither in app nor in code

Comment: If you have debugged and nothing found, then it's very hard to tell without anymore details.

Comment: You should google. https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium/issues/20 for example this issue describes problems similar to what you describe.
On a side note - provide more info. Your environment. Your code.

Comment: @Olga I just run the test directly on Chrome , windows 7

Comment: What information should i provide you about this issue?